# Force proxy with BCEL in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, bcel

Is there some way to replace a call like

```
Socket s = new Socket(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

with

```
Socket s = new Socket();
```

using BCEL because i can't figure out how.
I understand it would involve changing the InstructionList but i don't know how to scan for it and i don't know which opcodes to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with much shorter learning curve if you use [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) or similar high level tools.

For a low-level bytecode modification you can't get away without learning Java opcodes. A good starting point is [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11). Also, BCEL is not well documented and if you're flexible with choice of low level, I'd suggest using ASM framework. Here is corresponding tutorial on [implementing simple bytecode transformation](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial.html) with ASM. It is based on an older ASM version, but the ideas are still the same.

Comment: I am flexible the problem is I started with BCEL for this project... and i don't really want to go rewrite my code.